# WPF datatemplateselector not getting called

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datatemplateselector

Hello I'm trying to dynamically change datatemplate but my method SelectTemplate in class TreeViewItemTemplateSelector never getting called (I've checked it by debugger) :( please help me :)

Code from xaml MainWindow:

Code in code behind:

Comment: Your XAML looks a bit mal-formed, could be part of it (your selector in the `Window.Resources` is referencing static resources that don't exist in the XAML given, and your `TreeView.ItemSource` is set to `{Binding}`, should be `{Binding listmy}` from the looks of it.

Comment: Thx Psytronic for anwser but when I'm using {Binding listmy} I can't see any items in my treeView
I commented now line in MainWindow():

    //this.datacontext=listmy;

and in xaml I've deleted
tag <Window.Resources> to </Window.Resource>

Comment: Ahh, yeah, sorry missed that line. Do you get any errors in the output window when you start up the app?

Comment: no :( I don't have any errors :(

Comment: You twice set TreeViewItemTemplateSelector, in TreeView do ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" and delete the signing inside

Comment: Thank you michael I've try this too I deleted <TreeView.Resources>
and moved <datatemplate> to <window.resource>

And to treeView i've added ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"

And my method SelectTemplate still isn't called :( and to <window.resource> I added
<local:TreeViewItemTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"  ArticleTemplate="{StaticResource Article}" RegulationTemplate="{StaticResource Regulation}"  />

Comment: Update the code and we will take a look what we got.

Comment: I've too low reputation to do it :( if you can replay to my post I'll do it :)

Comment: Can you see any object TreeViewCustomItem in TreeView?

Comment: yes only using in xaml 
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
 And in code behind
this.DataContext = listmy;

Comment: Does it show Test.TreeViewCustomItem in TreeView or sth like that?

Comment: Test.Model.TreeViewCustomItem

Comment: I posted reply so you can update code.

Comment: What's the definition of your `TreeViewCustomItem` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that your `TreeViewCustomItem` is inheriting from `TreeViewItem`. (As seen in http://pastebin.com/jnP2nWMF)

Removing that inheritance (and the dependency property) causes the template selector to fire fine. What were/are you trying to achieve with the node item?

Looking at the OutputWindow, I get this message:

`System.Windows.Data Error: 26 : ItemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type; Type='TreeViewCustomItem'`

You don't have to have items inherit from the `TreeViewItem` in order to bind them to a `TreeView`, `TreeViewItem` is something that the `TreeView` uses to hold the data, and then the `DataTemplate` is used to present the data.

Comment: I don't need that property i used this previously... Thx for help

Answer (score 0):

Move DataTemplates from TreeView.Resources to Window.Resources

```
         <Window.Resources><DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate><DataTemplate x:Key="Regulation">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="Article">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" Foreground="Green"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>        
<local:TreeViewItemTemplateSelector x:Key="TemplateSelector" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"  ArticleTemplate="{StaticResource Article}" RegulationTemplate="{StaticResource Regulation}"  />
```

and make change

```
 <TreeView ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}" Height="409" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

Update code and we will see. I put similar code into VS and it works so we need to take a closer look. So i checked this and changed

```
public class TreeViewCustomItem
{
    public string Header { get; set; }
}
```

and this

```
 listmy = new ObservableCollection<TreeViewCustomItem> { new TreeViewCustomItem { Header = "xD" }, new TreeViewCustomItem { Header = "xxD" } };
        //treeView1.ItemsSource = listmy;
        this.DataContext = listmy;

 public class selector : DataTemplateSelector
{

    public DataTemplate RegulationTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        TreeViewCustomItem treeViewItem = item as TreeViewCustomItem;
        if (treeViewItem.Header == "xD")
        {
            return RegulationTemplate;
        }

        else
        {
            return DefaultTemplate;

        }
    }
}
```

and in XAML looks like this

```
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1.Views">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Regulation">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}" FontWeight="Bold"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    <local:selector x:Key="selector_" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}" RegulationTemplate="{StaticResource Regulation}"/>
</Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView Height="409" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="277"  
           ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector_}"/>      

</Grid>
```

And it works so my presumption is that problem is inside TreeViewCustomItem.

Comment: This didn't work :( here is my code behind and xaml
xaml: http://pastebin.com/kb5U8NaC
code behind: http://pastebin.com/YEzQcHh2

Comment: @matti2515 When I take that code from your pastebin (and remove your `Model.` DAL class references) it works as expected, breakpoint in the template selector class is being hit.

Comment: Thanks Psychotronic could you put this modified code here or in somewhere? Because seoriously this is whery weird :( I did the same and it didn't hit... :/

Comment: The only changes I made was to comment out the contents of the click/selected event handlers, and made the `myitems` an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead.

Comment: Thank you Psytronic it worked but why this don't work for TreeViewItem? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you pastbin the `TreeViewCustomItem` class?